# Dropdownlist not displaying content but white blanks XSLT

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

Ok, so i have managed to create a dropdownlist using html select,but the thing is, it is not displaying anything apart from white blank options. The number of options are exactly the same as what i have prepared, its just that i cant see the contents of it on dropdownlist.

Here is my XML

```
  <group name="Housing Type">
  <field is_admin_field="N" required="Y">
    <question_title>Which of the housing type best describes your residential?</question_title>
    <type>List</type>
    <db_field_name>which_of_the_housing_type_best_describes_your_residential</db_field_name>
    <options>
      <item score="0">3 - 5 room HDB</item>
      <item score="0">Executive Condominium </item>
      <item score="0">Landed 1 Floor</item>
      <item score="0">Landed 2 Floor</item>
      <item score="0">Landed 3 Floor</item>
      <item score="0">Landed 4 Floor</item>
      <item score="0">Landed 5 Floor</item>
    </options>
    <db_field_length>22</db_field_length>
    <additional_comment/>
  </field>
</group>
```

Here is my XSLT.  EDITED: Right now, i am able to see just one option.

```
  <xsl:if test="$type='List'">


        <select>
          <xsl:for-each select="./options">
          <option >
            <xsl:value-of select="item"/>

          </option>

          </xsl:for-each>
        </select>



    </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing '.' selector as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) , selects the current node much the same way as . selects the current folder in a file system path.

Try using

```
<xsl:if test="$type='List'">
  <xsl:for-each select="options">

    <select>
      <xsl:for-each select="item">
      <option >
        <xsl:value-of select="item"/>

      </option>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </select>


  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: I changed something. Please check my initial post.